# how to import external js and css on my code nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I starting a project in Nuxt.JS but already have my site in HTML + CSS + JS. I need just include these HTML on design of NuxtJS.

I have already tried to put the css as a global scope inside nuxt.config.js however in that way it will compile in SSR, and I would not like it. Just like import on html the css, js...

How could I import CSS and Javascript into my pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have to do is to include a head method in your page's export default.
You can learn more about the head method [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views#html-head)

```
<script>
export default {
  head () {
    return {
      script: [
        { src: 'path/to/your/js/file.js' }
      ],
      link: [
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'path/to/your/css/file.css' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**OR**

You can include them as if you'd do in html with `style` tag

```
<style src="path/to/your/css/file.css"><style>
<!-- You can also add "scoped" or "lang='sass'" etc in there -->
```

Comment: FYI: if it's dynamic page, like `_id`, if you would navigate from page with ID 1 to page with ID 2, your external script won't load, you have to refresh a browser or re-render your page component.

Comment: @Ejdrien Can I use conditions for import CSS in link section?